# STM32L0x1 incorrect temperature reading

Tags: sensor, stm32, temperature

I'm having trouble reading the temperature, its values are incorrect. The temperature in the room is 22C and the temperature of the sensor shows 55C (selfheating and the measurement error cannot be that big). I have many times checked the correctness of the code, and I use the functions recommended by the manufacturer (Code examples from reference manual). I have no idea why it doesn't work.

**Data:**

STM32L0x1 family MCU

3.3V supply voltage

Clock frequency: 2.097MHz (MSI)

**Problems I ruled out:**

1) ADC sampling time too short (it should be longer than 10us and it is).

2) I tested the code on different MCUs of the same model, and also on other models of STM32L0x1 family.

3) VDD of the chip is 3.3V, not e.g. 3.0V, there is no mistake here.

Below I paste the program code, as well as sample data from debugging in STM Studio.

```
#include "stm32l0xx.h"

#define TEMP130_CAL_ADDR ((uint16_t*) ((uint32_t) 0x1FF8007E))
#define TEMP30_CAL_ADDR  ((uint16_t*) ((uint32_t) 0x1FF8007A))
#define VDD_CALIB ((uint16_t) (300))
#define VDD_APPLI ((uint16_t) (330))

int32_t temperature_in_C;
uint16_t temperature_ADC_value;
int32_t temp130_cal_value;
int32_t temp30_cal_value;

int32_t ComputeTemperature(uint32_t measure)
{
    int32_t temperature;
    temperature = ((measure * VDD_APPLI / VDD_CALIB) - (int32_t) *TEMP30_CAL_ADDR );
    temperature = temperature * (int32_t)(130 - 30);
    temperature = temperature / (int32_t)(*TEMP130_CAL_ADDR - *TEMP30_CAL_ADDR);
    temperature = temperature + 30;
    return(temperature);
}

void ADC_Init()
{
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_ADCEN;      /* Enable ADC clock */

    ADC1->CFGR2 |= ADC_CFGR2_CKMODE_0
                |  ADC_CFGR2_CKMODE_1;      /* ADC Clock = PCLK (2.097MHz) */
    ADC->CCR |= ADC_CCR_LFMEN;              /* Enable if ADC Clock Freq < 3.5MHz */C
    ADC1->CFGR1 |= ADC_CFGR1_CONT;          /* Continous conversions */
    ADC1->CHSELR = ADC_CHSELR_CHSEL18;      /* Channel 18 - Temperature sensor */
    ADC1->SMPR |= ADC_SMPR_SMP;             /* Sampling time - 160.5 ADC cycles */
    ADC->CCR |= ADC_CCR_TSEN;               /* Enable temperature sensor */

    ADC1->ISR |= ADC_ISR_ADRDY;             /* Clearing bit ADRDY (ADC ready) */
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADEN;                /* Enable ADC */
    while((ADC1->ISR & ADC_ISR_ADRDY) == 0) /* Wait for turn on */
        ;
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADSTART;             /* Start */
}

int main(void)
{
    ADC_Init();

    while (1)
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) /* Delay */
          ;

      temperature_ADC_value = ADC1->DR;                 /* Debug */
      Temp130_cal_value = (int32_t)(*TEMP130_CAL_ADDR); /* Debug */
      Temp30_cal_value = (int32_t)(*TEMP30_CAL_ADDR);   /* Debug */

      temperature_in_C = ComputeTemperature(temperature_ADC_value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Data from the debugger]

Comment: What sensor? What circuit?

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry, I forgot to add this important information - it's an internal MCU temperature sensor

Comment: An internal running temperature of 55 doesn’t sound excessive at all.

Comment: @Andyaka Comparing the temperature calculated by me with the one calculated by others, whose topics I read, my is still too high. Moreover, my MCU is not connected to any current consuming device, the only thing it does is take an ADC measurement and convert its value to temperature in C degrees, so it should not get so hot.

Comment: 55C internal temperature should (if it's true) be easily detectable on the outside of the device package. What does your finger tell you? Does it feel hot?

Comment: @brhans I just checked the MCU temperature with a thermal imaging camera and the temperature was 22C.

Comment: The formula is right, so for some reason if the temperature is not 55, then the ADC gives you false readings. Double check that internal reference and temperature sensor are enabled. Then double check that the converted channel is correct, and that the result alignment and bitness is correct. Even if the sampling time is longest possible, I would not hammer the temp sensor with continuous readings, so try single reads, sample maybe once per second. The delay loop is not very long, and it might be optimized out by the compiler.

Comment: @Justme From what I've read in the reference manual, an internal reference is not needed for the temperature sensor to function properly. In any case, I also checked with the internal reference on, but there was no difference. The channel is right because when I heat up the MCU the ADC value increases. After changing the trigger of the ADC reading from continuous to single, unfortunately this didn't give any changes.

Comment: Well, to rule out hardware issues, do you use a custom board or dev kit? Can you post schematics and connections to MCU?

Comment: @Justme I use custom boards that are well tested with different ADC applications. I have checked the same code on different kinds of custom boards and even connected the MCU itself in the adapter, so I can rule out hardware problems with 99% probability.

I noticed that after changing VDD_APPLI to 3.0V (which is the voltage at which the manufacturer calibrates the temperature value) the result is 31C and is much closer to the expected one. I will look for a solution in this area

By the way, the errata doesn't say anything about possible errors related to the temperature sensor.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple, I was hinted at in the ST forum. It lacks ADC calibration. After adding the missing code, the reading is 30C, which means it's the expected one.